# Finding nonce such that SHA1 hash starts with four zeroes

Tags: blockchain, nonce

In my problem, I have to find a nonce. And nonce is basically the lowest integer for which `Blockhash` starts with 4 zeroes ("0000")

`Blockhash` = `sha1( prevblockhash, nonce, transactions)`

I am finding it iteratively starting nonce with 0, since I have to find the lowest integer which is the nonce. But then it is giving me TLE. is there any other way to find the lowest integer nonce the fastest ?

Comment: What is TLE? The whole point of mining is that (ideally) brute force is the fastest way to find the right nonce

Comment: yeah, I was solving the question in python, hence that might be the reason for the TLE. I should've solved the problem in C++.